# Switching between MySQL/SQL Server in EF6

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have a project that runs on both MySQL and SQL Server. During the last weeks I have managed to "migrate" it from plain old SQL to Entity Framework (using Spring dependency injection too) using a Database-first design based on the existing SQL Server schema.

Now I need to test with MySQL. Even if I used the "appropriate" MySQL configuration, the app will crash on a `ClassCastException` from `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection` to `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`

Code:

```
//Autowired by Spring
public auitool2014Entities DataContext{get;set;}

public IList<News> FindAllValid()
{
    return (from News news in DataContext.news where news.annullata == 0 select news).ToList();
}
```

Spring definition:

```
<object id="dataContext" singleton="false" scope="request" type="DiagnosticoSite.Models.auitool2014Entities, Auitool2014" factory-object="dataContextFactory" factory-method="Build" destroy-method="Dispose" ></object>
```

Spring factory:

```
public auitool2014Entities Build()
{
    return new auitool2014Entities();
}
```

Error message (translated from localized)

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.
```

Following the stack trace:

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.set_DbConnection(DbConnection value) +26
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.set_Connection(DbConnection value) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.set_DbConnection(DbConnection value) +41
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.set_Connection(DbConnection value) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.CommandHelper.SetStoreProviderCommandState(EntityCommand entityCommand, EntityTransaction entityTransaction, DbCommand storeProviderCommand) +123
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.PrepareEntityCommandBeforeExecution(EntityCommand entityCommand) +314
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +70
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +1283
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6() +185
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +448
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +271
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +251
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +648
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +68
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +68
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   DiagnosticoSite.Data.Managers.Spring.NewsManagerImpl.FindAllValid() in d:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Auitool\Auitool2014\Data\Managers\Spring\NewsManagerImpl.cs:16
```

Following the configuration:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

I basically changed my connection string to a MySQL connection string

```
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Auitool2014.csdl|res://*/Models.Auitool2014.ssdl|res://*/Models.Auitool2014.msl;provider=Mysql.Data.MysqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=localhost;Database=auitemp;Uid=root;Pwd=root;Allow Zero Datetime=True;CharSet=latin1;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=5&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

How can I switch after compilation between the two DBs? I mentioned Spring because my `DbContext` is `request`-scoped object that can be easily instantiated through a factory object.

### Investigation progress

I found that the stack trace reports the following class involved: `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy`. This obviously looks part of the SQL Server package. I need to understand how EF instantiates that. In EF source code I [see](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/ObjectQuery%60.cs)

```
var executionStrategy = ExecutionStrategy
                                    ?? DbProviderServices.GetExecutionStrategy(QueryState.ObjectContext.Connection, QueryState.ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace);
```

Really, that must be an instance of `MySql.Data.entity.EF6.MySqlExecutionStrategy`

Comment: Could you print the full error as it is?

Comment: I suspect that `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection` is derived from a different version of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` than the one you're using.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection is the class used by SQL Server. That and MySqlConnection derive from System.Data.Common.DbConnection implementing IDbConnection

Comment: Then I cannot understand why the code tries to convert it to `SqlConnection` rather than `IDbConnection`.

Comment: Because somewhere in the configuration there is still something telling EF to use SQL Server factories. Those need to be switched.  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.set_DbConnection(DbConnection value)  was invoked because somebody instantiated that

Comment: Where is the code of the faulting method, `FindAllValid()` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos updated with code, that's a simple LINQ query

Comment: Then where is DataContext created? How is its connection set?

Comment: DataContext is created as Spring object using a factory, basically with a call to new. This is a database-first model created with the wizard from the SQL Server db (I'm going to update the question), but basically the "auitool2014Entities"'s constructor calls base("auitool2014Entities") where auitool2014Entities is the connection string name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed changing EntityFramework's [configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

```
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

`MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration` is the key. Summarizing, in order to switch from SQL Server to MySQL I have to:

- Edit the damn connection string

  - Provider attribute is always `System.Data.EntityClient`
  - Within Connection *string*, change provider to `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`
- Replace `entityFramework` tag with the above

Comment: Can you please explain **Provider attribute is always System.Data.EntityClient** in your answer? I must keep the Provider Name in connectionString as the same for both Sql and MySql?